# how to divide a series by a series type using np.arange

Tags: python, pandas

I am wanting to do what the png illustration I've uploaded has, mainly have two columns with numbers in them. The code with the asterisk gets me the class and the 'SquareMiles'. The percentage column is more difficult to get. I am dividing an array of series numbers by the total series for that column with no success. How can this division go to completion?

```
Total = ca_land.get("SquareMiles")
Total1 = Total.sum()

percent = np.arange(Total/Total1)

* ca_classess = ca_land.groupby('Class').sum()

ca_classes = ca_classess.assign(
    Percentage = percent

)
```

[image]

Sample Data:

```
{'Class': {52: 'Forest & Woodland',   126: 'Forest & Woodland',   128: 'Forest & Woodland',   131: 'Forest & Woodland',   133: 'Forest & Woodland'},  'EcologicalSystem': {52: 'East Gulf Coastal Plain Near-Coast Pine Flatwoods - Open Understory Modifier',   126: 'California Central Valley Mixed Oak Savanna',   128: 'California Coastal Closed-Cone Conifer Forest and Woodland',   131: 'California Coastal Live Oak Woodland and Savanna',   133: 'California Lower Montane Blue Oak-Foothill Pine Woodland and Savanna'},  'SquareMiles': {52: 0.03266424261286,   126: 4350.262402786333,   128:
85.94309723386156,   131: 1726.1481557315549,   133: 6587.099312156705}}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: df.head().to_dict()

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'head' .

Comment: That error message is extremely weird. How exactly are you creating `df`? What is the output of `type(df)`?

Comment: fixed the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is necessary divide `SquareMiles` column after aggregating `sum`:

```
d = {'Class': {52: 'Forest & Woodland1', 126: 'Forest & Woodland1', 128: 'Forest & Woodland1', 131: 'Forest & Woodland', 133: 'Forest & Woodland'}, 'EcologicalSystem': {52: 'East Gulf Coastal Plain Near-Coast Pine Flatwoods - Open Understory Modifier', 126: 'California Central Valley Mixed Oak Savanna', 128: 'California Coastal Closed-Cone Conifer Forest and Woodland', 131: 'California Coastal Live Oak Woodland and Savanna', 133: 'California Lower Montane Blue Oak-Foothill Pine Woodland and Savanna'}, 'SquareMiles': {52: 0.03266424261286, 126: 4350.262402786333, 128: 85.94309723386156, 131: 1726.1481557315549, 133: 6587.099312156705}}
ca_land = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
Total1 = ca_land['SquareMiles'].sum()
ca_classes = (ca_land.groupby('Class').sum()
                     .assign(Percentage=lambda x: x['SquareMiles'] / Total1))
print (ca_classes)
                    SquareMiles  Percentage
Class                                      
Forest & Woodland   8313.247468    0.652046
Forest & Woodland1  4436.238164    0.347954
```

Or solution without assign is better readable:

```
ca_classes = ca_land.groupby('Class').sum()
ca_classes['Percentage'] =  ca_classes['SquareMiles'] / ca_land['SquareMiles'].sum()
print (ca_classes)
                    SquareMiles  Percentage
Class                                      
Forest & Woodland   8313.247468    0.652046
Forest & Woodland1  4436.238164    0.347954
```